# use append() and get() to form list of lists

Tags: r, list

I have a list of list names and corresponding lists like this:

```
list_names <- list("name1", "name2", "name3")
name1 <- list("apple", "banana", "orange", "peach")
name2 <- list("foo", "bar", "baz")
name3 <- list("house", "tree")
```

I now want to create a list of lists, with each list entry containing one of the lists `name1` - `name3`.

I tried the following code unsuccessfully but am stuck:

```
list_of_lists <- list()
for (i in 1:length(list_names)){
    ls <- list_names[[i]]
    append(list_of_lists, get(ls))
    }
```

The code runs without errors but `list_of_lists` us a `List of 0`, while I expect it to look like this:

```
> list_of_lists
$name1
$name1[[1]]
[1] "apple"
$name1[[2]]
[1] "banana"
$name1[[3]]
[1] "orange"
$name1[[4]]
[1] "peach"
$name2
$name2[[1]]
[1] "foo"
$name2[[2]]
[1] "bar"
$name2[[3]]
[1] "baz"
$name3
$name3[[1]]
[1] "house"
$name3[[2]]
[1] "tree"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append` doesn't work the same way as `list.append` in Python - it returns a new value rather than modifying the list in place.  So you should use `list_of_lists <- append(list_of_lists, get(ls))` in your loop.

You could also consider

```
list_of_lists <- lapply(list_names, get)
```

as a one-line (and maybe more R-idiomatic) solution.

Comment: Hmm.  Why the downvote?  Was it for jumping to conclusion that the confusion was based on familiarity with Python?

Comment: Nope, it was a correct hunch and I appreciate the thorough explanation as well as the hint to better (`R`-) syntax. Not sure who downvoted but wasn't me. ;)

Comment: Or just use mget.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating over the numerical list, iterate over each item:

```
list_of_lists <- list()
for (i in list_names){
   list_of_lists[[i]] <- get(i)
}
```